# Send event input value to components

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I have a generic component that contains an input, the value of this one is updated with onChange

```
export const SearchBar: React.FC = () => {

 const handleFilter = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   const searchWord = event.target.value
   // SEND THIS VALUE TO ANOTHER COMPONENT (SEARCHCOMPANY)
}

return ( <input type="text" onChange={handleFilter} placeholder="Type your search"/>
)}
```

The component that receives the data (from another file):

```
export const SearchCompany: React.FC<Props> = ({text}) => {
  // RECEIVE THE DATA
  const searchWord = text;
  return (<div></div>)
}
```

What is the best way to send the value of this input to one or more components of this kind?

Comment: needs more detail of code like where is `<SearchCompany />`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question but the component in question is in a separate file